# Adding minutes to base time

Tags: google-sheets

I have a base time of 10:30 AM set in a cell. I am entering the number of minutes, e.g. 4, in a different cell.

How can I add the minutes from the second cell to the first in order to display a new time?

[image: Example]

Comment: I think I figured it out!  =A4+time(0,B5,0)

Comment: Now, is there a way to drag down the formula without the time displaying, until an amount is added into column B?

Answer (score 7):

Your question is if you have a time-value stored in a cell, and and integer value stored in another cell representing minutes, in a third cell (cell-three) how do I add the minutes represented by the integer in cell-two to the time-value in cell-one?

To do this you need to understand date value. Date values, even though they display for instance 9/26/2016, they are actually stored as an integer 42639 whose units are days, where day zero is 12/30/1899.

Time-values are also stored as days. This means that 10:30am is really 10.5÷24 days.

If you want to add 4 minutes to the time-value you'll have to make sure that it is also converted to day-units. So 4 minutes = 4÷24÷60 days.

If cell A4 is what you are calling "Base Time" & cell A5 is the cell you wish to add minutes to, then you can accomplish this by the formula `=$A4+$B5/24/60`

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question in your comment...

```
=If((Isblank(B5)=true)," ",A4 + Time(0,B5,0))
```